# hand control to "thinkfan"

Tags: thinkpad, overheating, fan

I'm struggling to get [thinkfan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/thinkfan.1.html) set up and working on my [lenovo x250](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x250). I have it installed, but I'm not convinced it is controlling the fan speed. If I run:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

in the Terminal, I get:

```
status: enabled
```

But I'm under the impression it should be "disabled" when `thinkfan` is controlling things. If I run:

```
$ sudo thinkfan -n
```

I get:

```
WARNING: Using default fan control in /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

How do I hand off control of the fan to `thinkfan` (where I can adjust the setpoints)?

Comment: The man page (see first link above) notes you should  use tp_fan for a legacy thinkpad_acpi fan file or pwm_fan for a sysfs PWM file as _fan_ is depreciated. There's a forum which may have helpful info at https://sourceforge.net/p/thinkfan/discussion/905019

Comment: @ K7AAY: thanks for the reply. Pretty sure the X250 doesn't have a "legacy thinkpad_acpi" which would require me to use something other than thinkfan. I've found others on the web stating they have it running with T440s, X280s, etc. Do you actually use thinkfan? Just wondering if you have it up and running and can answer specific questions?

Comment: I have an x220 at home I can dust off and set up, but it make take a few days.

Answer (score 0):

first be sure the fan is enabled, as a default, its not :

```
echo "options thinkpad_acpi experimental=1 fan_control=1" >/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf
```

relaunch the module :

```
sudo rmmod thinkpad_acpi ; sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi
```

then edit the thinkfan config file

```
vi /etc/thinkfan.conf
```

mine is setup like that :

```
 tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan 

 tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 10, 15, 2, 10, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3)
 
 (0,    0,  41)
 (1,    40, 51)
 (2,    50, 56)
 (3,    55, 61)
 (4,    60, 65)
 (5,    64, 68)
 (7,    67, 32767)
```

the numbers are the temperature levels, for example > (5,   64, 68) means fan level 5 between 64 and 68 degrees

level 7, the maximum, above 67 degrees

```
service thinkfan restart
```

and check the messages with :

`journalctl -f`

Comment: Thanks @neofutur. Your instructions didn't work for me, probably because I've messed things up... I've got a file called thinkfan_acpi.conf in /etc/modprobe.d, but when I run a command such as `cat /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan_acpi.conf` I get "No such file or directory"... I suspect it's a permission thing, but I'm at a loss (yes, I'm a linux learner!). Any further suggestions welcome!

Comment: you have to do that as root, perhaps you use a different distribution and the file is not in /Etc/modprobe , also perhaps you have to create the fle yourself

Comment: have you done : "echo "options thinkpad_acpi experimental=1 fan_control=1" >/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf" as root ?